# p-value ratio for Likelihood Ratio Test with multicollinear data

Tags: regression, multicollinearity, likelihood-ratio

I have two datasets where my independent variables (of which I have 6) are highly correlated. In one dataset I know for certain that the dependent variable should only depend on 1 independent variable (say x6).

I want to test, using regression, whether the other dataset also only depends on 1 ind. variable or whether x1 through x5 are statistically significant in predicting the dependent variable. Both datasets have the same dependent variable.

Since these models are nested, I thought to use a Likelihood Ratio Test. I find the p-values for each dataset by comparing the full model with 6 independent variables to a reduced model with only 1 independent variable following the methodology here: https://www.statology.org/likelihood-ratio-test-in-python/

My p-values for the datasets come out to be 0.006426 and 0.00092, such that the p-value for the dataset where I am sure the dependence is only on one variable is 7x higher than the p-value for the unknown dataset.

Can I conclude from this that it is likely that the second dataset has some dependence on x1..x5 since if there was no dependence I would expect a very similar p-value? And does the multi-collinearity of my independent variables pollute the likelihood ratio test analysis?

Any help is much appreciated

Comment: Hi Tom, can you tell us how those p-values are computed? Furthermore, what tod you mean by _I am sure the dependence is only on one variable is 7x higher than the p-value for the unknown dataset._ ? At least, it's hard to tell if the multicollinearity is an issue without seeing the data or a proper analysis of the residuals.

Comment: @utobi Thanks for your reply. The p-values are computed as in https://www.statology.org/likelihood-ratio-test-in-python/ i.e. a log-likelihood of the linear regression results followed by calculating the chi-squared statistic and associated p-value. The p-value for the dataset where I am sure that the dependent variable is only a function of one of the ind. variables comes out ~7x higher (0.006426/0.00092) than the dataset for which I want to test that hypothesis. I've added some details in the main body!

Answer (score 1):

A couple things:

First: Your first paragraph is contradictory. When independent variables are highly collinear (which is not exactly the same as correlated) then the DV can't depend on only one variable, at least, not statistically. The different IVs are very similar. If the DV is related to one, it must be related to the others. It is possible that you can make a *substantive* argument that only one relationship is "real" (for some definition of "real") but they will all be statistically related.

Second: Maybe you already know this, but when you add IVs to a regression, you are testing whether that IV explains more variance, after controlling for what's already in the regression. With collinear variables, this is a) Often not what you want and b) Very hard to estimate.

Third: Although I am not completely sure what your p values are, it certainly looks like they are saying that the additional variables *are* significant.

Fourth: No, you can't look at the ratio of p values.  You could look at the effect sizes in the two data sets.